# Better file serialization way for proper cpu usage?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, serialization, cpu

I use following file serialization method to retrieve my data from disk.

```
public Vector load(String fileName) {

    try {

        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        Vector obj = (Vector) in.readObject();

        in.close();
        return obj;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have 35K sized file to be serialized. It works perfect but thread uses cpu violently and causes slow application to use. I load this file just once.

Is there any better way for serialization or is there any different way to handle usage cpu of thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also consider using Parcel for serialization, it's much more lightweight type of storage.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Vector, use ArrayList - there won't be any synchronization overhead.
2. If your operation is going long, just show a ProgressDialog within AsyncTask, like [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Comment: using ArrayList makes no difference. I tried. Progress still using high cpu.

Comment: operation must not disturb user who doesn't need this data immediately. Progress has to be go in background without forcing users wait time. So Progress Dialog is not my solution.  But UI gets slower when i serialize this data. I do not want this at all.